# Unwanted space at top of heading

Tags: html, css

I have two boxes of width `300px` each, displayed as `inline block`. Parent container is `600px` wide with `font-size: 0`. With in these boxes, heading `h3` has top margin of `20px`. Now if both strings in `h3` are equal, blocks are displayed correctly but as soon as I make one `h3` have smaller string, it goes down. 
Shouldn't this be aligned at the top ? How can I fix it ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="post-pack-fix">

<div class="home-box">

<h3><a href="#">Some title of the</a></h3>

<div class="meta">
 <a href="#">wordpress</a> / 2 days ago
</div>

<p>
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
<a href="#" class="more"> read more  &raquo; </a></p>

</div>
<div class="home-box">

<h3><a href="#">Some title of the post related to this</a></h3>

<div class="meta">
 <a href="#">wordpress</a> / 2 days ago
</div>

<p>
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
<a href="#" class="more"> read more  &raquo; </a></p>

</div> <!-- end home box -->

 </div> <!-- post pack fix -->
```

**Styles**

```
.post-pack-fix {
  font-size: 0;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}

.home-box {
  width: 300px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.home-box h3 {
  color: #464646;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0 9px 0;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

[image: see highlighted part]

**Equal 'h3' strings displayed correctly**

[image: Correct]

Comment: You didn't share your whole HTML and CSS, so I can't post a full example to demonstrate this...

Comment: thanks @jonathan .. i got it

Comment: Nah it's fine now. If you see my example I used my own modified Lorem Ipsum version of your code.

Comment: yes, that's awsome. actually i knew this could be a problem but I was applying `vertical-align: top` on `post-pack-fix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to the first `<div>`.

This is caused because the two `<div>`s are lined up at the baseline by default (`vertical-align: baseline`), as you can see in your picture.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjy3kaxd/) as a working example. Try removing `vertical-align: top` and see what happens.

Comment: @mallaudin I'm glad I helped (just don't forget to accept =))!

Answer (score 1):

The default CSS property for `inline-block` elements are `vertical-align:baseline`. So If you want to change the alignment apply it in your `home-box` code.

```
.home-box {
  width: 300px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```